# Some properties of finite group of order $p^aq^b$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, permutations

Let $G$ be a finite group of order $p^aq^b$ ( $p$, $q$ are two distinct primes and $a, b\geq 1$) with $\operatorname{Z}(G)=1$ and $P\in \operatorname{Syl}_p(G)$, $Q\in \operatorname{Syl}_q(G)$. Also let $\pi_e(G)$ denotes the set of all orders of elements in $G$. If $\pi_e(G)=\lbrace 1, p, q, pq\rbrace$, then, can we say that $P$ and $Q$ are abelian? ($\operatorname Z(G)$ is the center of $G$).

Comment: If we said that, then it would not be true.